# A gui library in c++ as web client

Tags: c++

I am trying to create web gui for my c++ application can any one recommend any good C++ library.I had a look at http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt . But i am not sure that is the only solution . Is connecting with python is a good solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are many other technologies more recommended for web applications, like php,asp.net, Java EE where there are many resources talking about them, and a lot of libraries exist for such technologies. So even if your backend is in C++ you can develop the front end with another techno, it will be more easy than trying to develop it with C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of http://www.treefrogframework.org/ as well.

In case your server is Windows based, another solution is expose your C++ application via REST with Casablanca,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca. Then provide the UI with a JavaScript framework.

Otherwise I would suggest using a language that makes it easier to bind with C++ for server development, like D (you can then use http://vibed.org/ for the web part).

Using Python will require you to use something like SWIG to be able to access the code. It all depends on how much you need to expose from the C++ side.